# React Complex Form Editing key value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a form to edit a key/value pair object, see picture:

[image: Key Value Pair Editor]

This is the object that I get from the backend that I stored in the container component.

```
items: [{
    name: "Product Name",
    sku: "00001",
    attributes: {
        width: "value",
        height: "value",
        length: "value",
        color: "value"
    }
},
{
    name: "Product Name 2",
    sku: "00002",
    attributes: {
        description: "Hello World",
        weight: "250",
        quantity: "500",
        hello: "World"
    }
}]
```

I then pass the data into a child component via props. This is the code for the form:

```
class EditForm extends Component {
    render() {
        let editForm = this.props.items && this.props.items.map((item, idx) => {
            return(
                <tr key={item.sku}>
                    <td className="edit-table">
                        <input 
                            value={item.name}
                            name={item.name}
                            onChange={(e)=> this.props.onChange(e, idx)}
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td className="edit-table">
                        <ul className="item-attributes">
                            {Object.keys(item.attributes).map((key) => {
                                return (<li key={key}>
                                                    <label>{key}</label>
                                                    <input 
                                                        value={item.attributes[key]} 
                                                        onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange(e, idx) }
                                                    />
                                                </li>)
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        })

        return(
            <table className="editcontainer-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>SKU</th>
                        <th>Attributes</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {editForm}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, this is where I'm stuck, I'm trying to figure out how the onChange function would work for me to edit the objects in the state and send back to the server for updating.

Comment: Do you use form tag for your EditForm component somewhere?

Comment: There is a <form> just before the <table>.

Comment: Where are you storing the state of the form? is it in a parent of EditForm?

Comment: Yes, the state is stored in the parent of EditForm, which is then passed down as props to the EditForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give the item name input a `name="name"` attribute
2. Give the attribute inputs names per the attribute: `name={key}`

You can now identify what's being edited in `onChange` - make the appropriate state change based on the index and input name being changed.

e.g. (using `import update from 'immutability-helper'`) `onChange` might look like this:

```
  onChange = (e, index) => {
    let {name, value} = e.target
    let updateSpec
    if (name === 'name') {
      updateSpec = {
        [index]: {
          name: {$set: value}
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      updateSpec = {
        [index]: {
          attributes: {
            [name]: {$set: value}
          }
        }
      }
    }
    this.setState({items: update(this.state.items, updateSpec)})
  }
```

---

Here's an example app which shows this solution in action:

- [Live version](https://44512259-react-complex-form-editing-key-value-pair.surge.sh)
- [Full example source](https://github.com/insin/stackoverflow/blob/master/44512259-react-complex-form-editing-key-value-pair/index.js)

Comment: Thanks. However, the performance seems to be really slow when the SKU items are more than 10+ with 20+ attributes on each sku.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `onChange` function in your Container to be the following:

```js
onChange = (e, sku, field) => {
  const updatedItems = this.state.items.map(e => { 
    if (e.sku !== sku) return e;
    if (field === 'name') {
      e.name = e.target.value;
    } else {
      // has to be attributes
      e.attributes[field] = e.target.value;
    }
    return e;
  });
  this.setState({
    items: updatedItems,
  })
}
```

Added sku parameter to identify the item in items array and the field you want to change. Since sku is not going to change, we can use this as the item identifier. This way, you can change the product name and its respective attributes. For full working code, see the code example below.

```js
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [{
        name: "Product Name",
        sku: "00001",
        attributes: {
          width: "value",
          height: "value",
          length: "value",
          color: "value"
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Product Name 2",
        sku: "00002",
        attributes: {
          description: "Hello World",
          weight: "250",
          quantity: "500",
          hello: "World"
        }
      }],
    }
  }
  
  onChange = (e, sku, field) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    const updatedItems = this.state.items.map(item => { 
      if (item.sku !== sku) return item;
      if (field === 'name') {
        item.name = e.target.value;
      } else {
        // has to be attributes
        item.attributes[field] = e.target.value;
      }
      return item;
    });
    this.setState({
      items: updatedItems,
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    // log new state here
    console.log(this.state.items);
    return <EditForm onChange={this.onChange} items={this.state.items} />
  }
  
}

class EditForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let editForm = this.props.items && this.props.items.map((item, idx) => {
      return(
        <tr key={item.sku}>
          <td className="edit-table">
            <input 
                value={item.name}
                name={item.name}
                onChange={(e)=> this.props.onChange(e, item.sku, 'name')}
            />
          </td>
          <td className="edit-table">
            <ul className="item-attributes">
              {Object.keys(item.attributes).map((key) => {
                  return (<li key={key}>
                                      <label>{key}</label>
                                      <input 
                                          value={item.attributes[key]} 
                                          onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange(e, item.sku, key) }
                                      />
                                  </li>)
              })}
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    })

    return(
      <table className="editcontainer-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Attributes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           {editForm}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have another issue though. In the onChange function, the value of `this` does not have setState or the state. If I `console.log(this)` the value of `this` is the props that I pass from the parent container to the EditForm component

Comment: Really? this should have setState and state because I am using it inside. Can you show me where you log and the the output?

Comment: actually adding `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` on the parent component constructor solved the issue

Comment: Perhaps you've added a new method. Alternatively, you can use arrow function like I have on onChange method in Container component.